# sound recorder doesn't record

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

With Ubuntu 13.04 I noticed that Sound Recorder seems to be broken, i.e. I can't get it to record anything. When I press on the record button the Level input remains grayed out. When I open the volume control the top of the list value Digital Input is always chosen, but I can change it to Rear Microphone which I see responds nicely on the Input level, but sound recorder doesn't respond to the change.

I tried Audacity and there I can choose the source as the rear microphone and audacity works fine. Sound recorder used to work as well. Skype also works with no problems.

Any suggestions on how to get it back on line?
Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Found this bug report after some googling. Hope it gets fixed soon. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/1106908